# set basefield to zero

Tags: c++, stl, iomanip

I know that `basefield` is a mask for `dec/oct/hex`, All i want is to unset them using `setf` stream function but no matter how much i try it's not right, so i wrote the following example to help me understand how flags internally looks for all possible values of `basefield`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef ios_base::fmtflags fmt;
    fmt a, b, c = cout.basefield;

    cout << "basefield: " << hex << c << endl;

    cout << dec;
    a = cout.flags();
    b = a & c;
    cout << "\ndec flags:\n";
    cout << "   a: " << hex << a << endl;
    cout << "   b: " << hex << b << endl;

    cout << oct;
    a = cout.flags();
    b = a & c;
    cout << "\noct flags:\n";
    cout << "   a: " << hex << a << endl;
    cout << "   b: " << hex << b << endl;

    cout << hex;
    a = cout.flags();
    b = a & c;
    cout << "\nhex flags:\n";
    cout << "   a: " << hex << a << endl;
    cout << "   b: " << hex << b << endl;

    cout.setf(cout.flags() & ~cout.basefield);
    a = cout.flags();
    b = a & c;
    cout << "\nunset basefiled:\n";
    cout << "   a: " << hex << a << endl;
    cout << "   b: " << hex << b << endl;
}
```

g++ 4.8.1 results are:

```
basefield: 4a

dec flags:
   a: 1002
   b: 2

oct flags:
   a: 1040
   b: 40

hex flags:
   a: 1008
   b: 8

unset basefiled:
   a: 1008
   b: 8
```

When unset all bases flags value are set to be same as hex flags, so i run the code Visual C++ 2008 and Intel C++ XE and the result was:

```
basefield: e00

dec flags:
   a: 201
   b: 200

oct flags:
   a: 401
   b: 400

hex flags:
   a: 801
   b: 800

unset basefiled:
   a: 801
   b: 800
```

Hex flags seems to be exact with all bases unset.

All i want is to set the flags to a value other than `dec\oct\hex` so when i implement my own manipulator i can detect which format is in use my formats or stream formats.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not the way to go about creating your own manipulators

Comment: Will i want to create `bin` manipulator, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You'll need to create a new manipulator. Perhaps you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unset flags with [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) overload with single parameter - it can only set new flags. Use [`unsetf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/unsetf) or `setf` with two parameters to unset flags.